# KeyEventArgs KeyData.ToString() returns backwards key press

Tags: c#, tostring, keyeventargs

I have a KeyEvent called Bind that captures two key presses (Ctrl + Ins)
I want to return this as a string but when I do using (Bind.KeyData.ToString()) the string is backwards and instead of ( Control, Insert ) it returns ( Insert, Control ). How do I fix this?

```
private KeyEventArgs Bind = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Control | Keys.Insert);
```

And to call I use

```
Bind.KeyData.ToString()
```

Comment: Nobody can tell that you are asking a [winforms] question.  Consider `new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(Bind.KeyData)` to generate the kind of string that is used in menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct you result string manually:

```
string result = $"{Bind.Modifiers}, {Bind.KeyCode}";
```